# Why is my probit analysis resulting in coefficients outside 0 and 1?

Tags: logistic, stata

I am doing a probit on a binary dependent variable.  The binary dependent variable has observed outcomes of 227 successes and 1704 failures.  If I run predict after the probit I get probabilities that make sense for each set of observations, but I want to be able to make sense of the beta coefficients that I get from a straight probit analysis. The same thing happens with logit.

Comment: What exactly is the question?  Your title implies that you're getting predicted probabilities smaller than 0 or larger than 1 but your "question" says that the probabilities make sense.  What exactly is the issue?  My inclination is that you might not understand the link function and what it does with regard to a generalized linear model (in this case either probit or logistic regression) and you're trying to make predictions by hand but those don't end up making sense because you're doing them wrong.

Comment: I would guess you are looking at the prediction in the probit scale and not in the response scale. If using R, look at the predict.glm function.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think [Dason](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/4737/dason)'s reply is appropriate: your title does not fit your question. If you estimate a probit/logit model, $P(Y=1|X,\beta)$, by the plugg-in solution, $P(Y=1|X,\hat\beta)$ your probability is always between 0 and 1, no matter what the values of the covariates $X$ are. If you find a probability outside $(0,1)$, you are not using a probit/logit model. Now, if you ask about the meaning of $\beta$, this is indeed a real number. For instance, in the logit model, since
$$
\frac{P(Y=1|X,\beta)}{P(Y=0|X,\beta)} = \exp\{ \beta^t X \}
$$
the coefficients of $\beta$ can be explained in terms of log-odds-ratios:
$$
\log\left( \frac{P(Y=1|X,\beta)}{P(Y=0|X,\beta)} \right) = \beta^t X
$$
so, when considering covariate $x_1$ for instance,
$$
\log\left( \frac{P(Y=1|x_1=2,X_{-1},\beta)}{P(Y=0|x_1=2,X_{-1},\beta)} \right) 
- \log\left( \frac{P(Y=1|x_1=1,X_{-1},\beta)}{P(Y=0|x_1=1,X_{-1},\beta)} \right)
= \beta_1 
$$
which means that the coefficient $\beta_1$ of $x_1$ is the amount the log-odds-ratio changes when the covariate $x_1$ is changed by one unit.